# During the quest “Uncovering the Past”, what impact does saving the AI have?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

During the quest "Uncovering the Past" on Voeld, you come across an ancient artificial intelligence and are put on the spot to make a choice about its future. You're able to destroy it, keep it for yourself, or return it to it's original owners. The artificial intelligence does not recogonize it's original owners as such, though.

What is the impact of saving the AI and keeping it for yourself in comparison to destroying it or giving it back to the original owners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save the Ancient AI and keep it for yourself, it is delivered to SAM Node on the Nexus and you get to experience some disturbing conversations between the Ancient AI and SAM.

One of the conversations was the Ancient AI asking if SAM is able to kill everyone on the Nexus - SAM says yes but only in extreme circumstances and then the Ancient AI asks how he would do it. That's the most disturbing thing I witnessed the AI say.

The Ancient AI says other worrying stuff too like sneaking on missions in your head with SAM.

Answer (score 2):

Saving the AI and keeping it for yourself will make the AI appear in SAM Node on the Hyperion. You'll also receive a very unhappy email from Evfra but this doesn't appear to directly impact anything more than a couple of lines of dialogue later on.

If you save the AI and return it to the Angaran then they'll utilize it to provide assistance to you during a mission later in the game.

Obviously if you destroy the AI, it's destroyed. This will be seen as the "correct choice" in the heat of the moment, considering how on the spot you were put.